# How to install Open edX offline (without internet)

Tags: openedx

I want to install Open edX, But I don't have the internet on a production machine. Can I install Open edX offline (without internet)?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible as the native scripts download various libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can install OpenedX via Bitnami - https://bitnami.com/stack/edx
You can download the installer on a machine having internet connection and then transfer it to your production machine and run it there. That should work.